# UAngular 5: mat-table [dataSource] within *ngFor loop, how to pass data sources from an array

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5

what is the way to pass data sources from an array to a mat-table within *ngFor loop. I.e. I use *ngFor to create multiple tables, each table requires a datasource, but when I try the following it doesn't work:

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSources[i]">
```

while 'i' is defined prior in html template:

```
<mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let customer of customers; let i = index">
```

**Update:**

the following worked for me, I added dataSource to each customer object instead of keeping it separate and trying to access via 'i' index

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="customer.dataSource">
```

Comment: What do you mean by does not work? Any error?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<mat-table *ngFor="let dataSource of dataSources" #table [dataSource]="dataSource">
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: thanks, but it's not exactly the syntax as *ngFor already iterates through customers. I figured it out, though

Comment: @Paul do you still have the answer?